# how to take the data of a td and transform it into variable php?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I'm trying to take the values of the `td` that contains id
this is my JavaScript code:

```
function Functiontd() {
    var variable = document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = variable;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>Option</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark </td>
        <td><input type="submit" onclick="Functiontd()" ;></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>Francis </td>
        <td><input type="submit" onclick="Functiontd()" ;></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<div id="content"></div>
```

At the time of calling the onclick only shows me the value 1 of the first td
if I press the button of the second row does not appear the 45 only the 1

How could I make each time I press the button show me the value of the td of the id of that row? and then bring that JavaScript value to a php variable?

Comment: For the first goal, get the firts `td` value of the row where the click event occurs, you will need to pass `this` as the argument of `Functiontd()`. Then, the logic will be to use `this`, and get his parent node, then get the first child of this parent. For the second goal, you should remenber that javascript runs on client side, and php on server side, to pass a value from javascript to php you will have to make a `POST` call, or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you are always recovering the first td

```
 var variable=document.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].innerHTML;
```

You should click and recover that particular element and go up in the hierarchy of nodes

Use [innerText](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp) instead of [innerHtml](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

My example is based on the [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object to interact with server. You are free to use any service to make the request asynchronous to the server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>Option</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="getId(this)">GetId</button></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>Francis</td>
        <td><button type="button" onclick="getId(this)">GetId</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    <script>
      function getId(element) {
        const currentTr = element.parentElement.parentElement;
        const id = parseInt(currentTr.children[0].innerText);

        goToServer(id);
      }

      function goToServer(id) {
        const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open('POST', './queryUser.php', true);
        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 200) {
                alert(this.responseText);
            }
        };

        // Data to send
        xmlhttp.send(`id=${id}`);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
enter code here
```

**QueryUser.php**

```
<?php
$id = $_POST["id"];

echo 'Response: '. $id;
```

The example is quite basic but it helps you in your learning.

**Useful resources**

- [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)
- [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)
- [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: I have never used ajax, I did a little research and I was using this but it does not work  :             function getId(element) {
        var currentTr = element.parentElement.parentElement;

          var id = parseInt(currentTr.children[0].innerText);

          $.ajax({
                url: './queryuser.php',
                type: "POST",
                dataType:'text',
                data: {'id': id},


            });
      }

Comment: Ok, modified my answer with an example using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

As D. Smania mentions your question consists of two questions. To solve the first one how to get the correct id you can try the following

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('click', handleClick));
        
function handleClick(event) {
  const id = this.closest('tr').children[0].textContent;
  
  document.querySelector('#content').textContent = id;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>Option</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Mark </td>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>Francis </td>
        <td><input type="submit"></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<div id="content"></div>
```

About the second one, is a bit more complex to answer because you do not mention the context, but a couple of options could be, save the id obtained in an input:hidden and send it in a form post. Another option could be that this previous process is done with some ajax call

Comment: the context is that I need that id to send it in an sql SELECT query
in a second button that opens a modal with all user data